# What are the required Plist settings for the AWSCognitoIdentityProvider in iOS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-ios

I've been using the IOS AWS SDK and generally it's pretty awesome, even if the documentation is anything but.  ;)  For reasons not germane to this post, I was attempting to use the AWSCognitoIdentityProvider provided in the AWS SDK.  Unfortunately the moment the app attempts to instantiate this object, the following error is received:

> ...exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The service ?
>   configuration is `nil`. You need to configure `Info.plist` or set 
>   `defaultServiceConfiguration` before using this method.'

Familiar territory, I had seen it with S3, etc...it means you need it configured in the PList.  Problem - unlike S3, there doesn't seem to be any documentation on what the PList settings *should* be for this object.  The AWS MobileHub sample code doesn't utilize this object and the Github samples don't either.  So what's the actual configuration for this object supposed to be?

Answer (score 2):

Aaaaand answering my own question (after some trial and error educated guessing) so that this can help other poor souls...

The PList setting that you require inside your "AWS" dict section is:

```
<dict>    
        <key>CognitoIdentityProvider</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Default</key>
            <dict>
               <key>PoolId</key>
                <string>[Your Pool ID]</string>
                <key>Region</key>
                <string>[Your Region]</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
</dict>
```

Those of you who've worked and bled for Cognito before will note that these settings are identical to those you supply for the CredentialsProvider/CognitoIdentity configuration (which do have examples in MobileHub).  Hopefully this saves you tearing your eyeballs out.

Comment: That isn't a full plist entry.  What is the value between <key> </key>?

Comment: a) There's no empty <key> tag that I can see in the above section, so not sure what you're referring to.



b) This answer assumes you're already working with AWS configurations in the first place (and thus this is yet another entry inside of that AWS config dict entry, just like AWS' own docs).  However I've clarified the answer to indicate this goes in the AWS section, in the event that's what you were asking.

Comment: Perhaps you don't need a key tag before it.  Anyhow, what I meant was "That isn't a full plist entry. What is the value between <key>      and    </key>?   Or, where is the key tag?"

Comment: Hence my clarification above in the quesiton edit - this is not a *full* plist entry, only the subsection of the plist that pertains to the AWSCognitoIdentityProvider.  If you've set up an AWS configuration before this structure is familiar.  =)

Comment: Yea.  I was looking for a full example at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Below solution works for CognitoSync

```
    <key>AWS</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Cognito</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Default</key>
            <dict>
                <key>PoolId</key>
                <string>[Your Pool ID]</string>
                <key>Region</key>
                <string>[Your Region]</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```